# Interaction with search bar does not work swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am including a search bar by code and enabling interaction using the code below, the search bar is displayed but when I click on the field editing is not enabled:

```
let searchTableViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchBarTableVC") as? SearchBarTableVC
    searchTableViewController?.handleMapSearchDelegate = self
    searchTableViewController?.mapView = self.mapView

    searchBarController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchTableVC)
    searchBarController?.searchResultsUpdater = searchTableVC

    let searchBar = searchBarController?.searchBar

    searchBar?.sizeToFit()
    searchBar?.placeholder = "Digite o local"
    searchBar?.tintColor = UIColor.red
    searchBar!.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    searchBar?.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "ColorTransparent")

    navigationItem.titleView = searchBarController?.searchBar

    searchBarController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchBarController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

    definesPresentationContext = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using iOS 11, the preferred way is simply to write:

`navigationItem.searchController = searchController`

That's all. You don't have to position the search bar or put it in any view.